# Is there any way to compile source code in subdirectories via gnu make

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to write Makefile script which will compile my project in VS Code which contains sub directories. My project structure looks like:

```
src
| - subdirectory1
|   | - file1.cpp
|   | - file2.cpp
| - subdirectory2
|   | - sub3
|   |   | - file4.cpp
```

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: The Makefile script can be used with source files in subdirectories.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible.

Comment: @rustyx If only your comment was an answer, I would certainly vote to make it as accepted one.